# How do I create a new column that indicates whether a different column contained NA or not?

Tags: r

I want to create a new column that reports whether a separate column contains (=1) or does not contain (=0) data.

One way to do this is to create a column slugged with all 0 and then replace if the focal column is not NA - but this seems very sloppy to me. I'm guessing there is a one liner (if:else style) that is more elegant. I'm extremely new to R and have not programmed in many years.

Please advise.

Two liner:

> data$New_Column <- 0
>
> data$New_Column [!is.na(data$FocalColumn)] <- 1

Comment: I think @sgibb's answer is what you're looking for, but I also don't think that the alternative is "very sloppy." I'd like to leave that description available for a number of more heinous crimes.

Comment: @Sophologist A fair point. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ifelse`:

```
data$NewColumn <- ifelse(is.na(data$FocalColumn), 0, 1)
```

Or convert the logical values to numeric:

```
data$NewColumn <- as.numeric(!is.na(data$FocalColumn))
```

Comment: W00t! My intuition was correct, and you have provided me with the ifelse I have dreamed about. Thanks!